# Use grep to find a folder and then rename it

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, grep, rename

Hello I'm struggling with this topic for a while now

I have a folder with lots of subfolders. One of them has 'Map' in its name, but could be called
'12303934Map7899hhh'. Its different every time and it follows no specific structure.

with `ls | grep Map`  this folder can be displayed.
But now I want that the search outcome will always directly be named to 'Map' with skipping the rest. How can I do that?

Comment: Note: in Unix/BSD/Linux, the term is "directories" and not the Windows user defined term of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
mv *Map* Map
```

Example shell session:

```
joni@tammi:/tmp/base$ mkdir 12303934Map7899hhh
joni@tammi:/tmp/base$ ls -F # Let's see if it exists...
12303934Map7899hhh/
joni@tammi:/tmp/base$ mv *Map* Map
joni@tammi:/tmp/base$ ls -F  # Let's see if it was renamed...
Map/
```

Grep is really not the right tool to use here. If you need to use grep in some way in the solution for whatever reason, you can write:

```
mv "$(ls | grep Map)" Map
```

This solution has some pitfalls though. For example it's possible to create a file name that includes an embedded line break, and `grep` would break it apart. A better solution has been suggested in the comments below.

Comment: Yeah but it should be just renamed since a new folder called 'Map' does not exist

Comment: And I don't want to have it have as a subfolder

Comment: `mv` renames files and directories. What do you mean by not having it as "subfolder" do you want to move it out of the current directory? Can you explain these extra requirements in the question?

Comment: The line of code as you suggested does not work. It says 'There is no directory called Map'. I want every directory that has the word 'Map' inside its name just renamed to simply 'Map'.

Comment: Where do you see this "There is no directory called Map" error? I've added an example shell session to the answer to demonstrate that this command works. *Are you saying you have more than one directory with "Map" in its name?* In the question you wrote "One of them has 'Map' in its name"

Comment: I tried it several times, but 'target is not a directory'. I recreated your example and the command mv is always interpreted as 'move to' for my console. So if there's is no such directory as 'map' it wont move anything. For me it is does not work as a renaming command

Comment: That means you have more than one file or directory that has "Map" in its name. You can rename only one of them to "Map". How do you know which one?

Comment: No there is only one with the word 'Map' inside, but it can't be renamed, see comment above

Comment: Can you update the question to add what you've tried, and what happened as a result? Also add details about which operating system and which shell you are using. `mv` is THE command to rename files and directories, the computer you are using would not work if it didn't rename.

Comment: @Dontwastetime - a shot in the dark: are you removing the `*`s from around `*Map*` before executing the `mv` command? If so - don't do that! Be clear about the error message you're getting though - `'There is no directory called Map'` and `'target is not a directory'` are 2 different error messages (the first means you're doing `mv Map foo` when `Map` doesn't exist, the second that you're doing `mv x y` where `x` is a directory and `y` is an existing file), tell us what exact command you're running and what exact error message you're getting.

Comment: @Joni please don't suggest `mv "$(ls | grep Map)" Map` - it's just wrong in multiple ways.

Comment: @EdMorton the OP specifically asks for a solution using `grep`. It might be because it's a constraint imposed by a homework question, or some other external factor. Stackoverflow is frequently criticized for answering "how do I use X" questions with "don't use X, use Y" because it completely ignores the constraints the user might have. For me, if the OP wants a solution with `grep`, the OP gets a solution with `grep`. Can you think of a better solution that still involves `grep` in some way?

Comment: Yes `printf '%s\0' * | grep -z` for one would be better than parsing the output of `ls` (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) BUT it's just not the right approach so if a teacher is asking for it they need that feedback and if a student thinks it's a good answer then they need to know it's not before submitting their homework. We **frequently** get people asking how to do something with a completely inappropriate tool, telling them how (without explaining why not to) should be avoided.